# What is the advantage of a custom API in Auth0?

Tags: jwt, single-page-application, auth0, ktor

**Question**

I got a problem with understanding some basic thing about auth0, probably someone can help me out.

In the tutorial [SPA + API](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api) one of the first lines in the TDLR is this:

> Both the SPA and the API must be configured in the Auth0 Dashboard

I dont understand why I need to configure the API on Auth0. My code seems to work so can anyone help me understand if I do something wrong or what the advantages are if I actually add a custom API in my dashboard?

**Setup**

- SPA (React)
- Auth0
- REST API (ktor)

**What I do**

- Created a SPA on Auth0
- Login on my SPA through Auth0 to get a JWT (google token)
- Sending the JWT as authentication bearer in my calls to the REST API
- REST API verifies the JWT token with a JWK provider using the Auth0 url `mydomain.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json`.
- Authentication seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, I am assuming that your authentication request includes audience parameter which represents your custom API(Rest API)right now. In oauth2 terms, it is called Resource Server. Each resource server can have many permissions which you include in the scope when initiating the authentication request.   Let's step back and talk about the token format. Auth0 issues token in two formats:

- Opaque strings: When not using a custom API
- JSON Web Tokens (JWTs): When using a custom API

https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/reference/access-token/access-token-formats#how-does-all-this-affect-the-token-format-

As explained above link, the token format depends on the audience (Custom API) parameter.  Therefore, when the authentication request includes audience, auth0 issues JWT token with all necessary permission. Then, you need to validate the JWT token in your API server before returning the resources to your front end client.

It should make sense why you need to create custom API in auth0 and define permissions. If you do not create custom API in auth0, there is no way to know what kind of permission you need in the token which will generate an error(invalid audience specified)

Comment: When Im doing my WebAuth object Im adding an 'audience' key with mydomain/userinfo as value. the scope is 'openid email profile'. I receive an access token and id token and with the access token I can get the user profile. So I still having problems understanding what I would do if I would add a custom api. Your link mentions that this access token is in the opaque format. When I would configure a custom api, I would add the api identifier as audience and receive a token in the JWT format, right? I would use that to send it to my REST api and check it there? But I dont get why this is better.

Comment: If you provide openid as scope, it should automatically add /userinfo as the audience. Alternatively, you can provide /userinfo as audience. The access token is not a JWT token in that stage. It is a Opaque token and can only be used to call /userinfo endpoint. You can not use this access token to call your Rest API endpoint. Now, pass your custom API identifier as audience and compare the token.  You can use https://jwt.io to decode the token and examine the token content. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis

Comment: I made an authorize without the audience and compared the token to an authorize with the api identifier as audience. I see that the access token is much longer and has the permissions in it I added through a user role in auth0. I still dont understand how I would use this in my application. In the end I can just verify the jwt on the rest api backend and check if the user has the right role to access a route. Thanks for the help tho, I will try to re-read the documentation...

Comment: Simply, the roles or permissions can be used to secure your API endpoint and secure from unauthorized request. https://auth0.com/docs/scopes/current#ways-to-use-scopes  example: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs

Comment: so let me summarize: Im using the authorization with my custom api to get the scopes/permissions for the user. after that I know which scopes I have access to as part of my token. Now I call my rest api with this token and I secure every route by checking if the user has the permission/scope for this route? "read:posts" would probably needed for a route like "GET posts". BUT this would be nearly the same as if I would just add a role to each user and compare in the backend if the user has access to a specific route based on his role - correct?:)

Comment: yes. Now managing this in your server can be complicated. Auth0 provides RBAC out of box and you can use auth0 dashboad to include both roles and permission in the token by simply enabling the feature. Therefore, you can assign appropriate roles and permission using the auth0 dashboard without any code change.  Thus, the workload in your server down to zero. https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/rbac https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/guides/how-to The sample use case can give you a more detailed understanding. https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/sample-use-cases-rbac

Comment: Appreciate it. Accepted your answer which I guess I understand finally:)